# matlab: making the domain of a function dependent on the domain of the inputs

Tags: matlab

Suppose one has functions `f(i)` and `g(j)`. How could one write a function `h(k)`, where the domain `k` of `h` is made up of all `k=i+j` (i.e., each point `h(k)` is some function of `f` at `i` and `g` at `j` for all pairs of `i` and `j` satisfying `k=i+j`). For instance:

[image]

for all `k=i+j`. The domain of `h` would thus be `k=2:25` and, for instance, `h(3)` would be equal to `f(1)*g(2) + f(2)*g(1)` since both of these combinations satisfy `k=i+j`.

This is simple to do using loops, but I wish to compose the function in anonymous function form (i.e., `h = @(k) f(i) ... g(j)`). How can this be accomplished?

Comment: According to your formal example (with the sigma sums), `h` is constant. Want you actually want is an algorithm to find all valid sets of `i,j` for a given `k`, such that `k=i+j`. Sounds like a math problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let `a` and `b` be known variables for the domains i and j. Then the function you describe might look like this:

`fun=@(k) sum(sum(transpose(f1(k-b(ismember(b,(k-a)))))*f2(b(ismember(b,(k-a))))))`

where `f1` and `f2` are anonymous functions corresponding to f(i) and g(j). `k` is a valid scalar.

Note: it might not be considered good practice to use an anonymous function for something non-trivial.

Note2: I haven't considered scenarios with non-unique domains for i and j, nor negative values.